# Best Nagios plugin for SMARTd / smartmontools?

Tags: monitoring, hard-drive, nagios, smart

I've installed SMARTd / smartmontools on a server and I want to monitor it over Nagios. However on Monitoring Exchange, I see several plugins

- http://www.monitoringexchange.org/cgi-bin/page.cgi?g=2897.html;d=1
- http://www.monitoringexchange.org/cgi-bin/page.cgi?g=2940.html;d=1
- http://www.monitoringexchange.org/cgi-bin/page.cgi?g=2480.html;d=1
- http://www.monitoringexchange.org/cgi-bin/page.cgi?g=Detailed%2F2169.html;d=1
- anything else?

Which ones are good? What would you recommend?

Both the nagios server and the server with smartd / harddisks are Ubuntu server.

Comment: I googled for this question, found my question from ~5 years ago, and all those links are dead now :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try build-in `check_ide_smart`

Answer (score 3):

Well because you are using Linux, nix the first one, it is for windows.

I am personally using the second one. As a relative nagios newcomer I found it easy to integrate, even with no documentation from the author. You will have to setup the check_command config and stuff.

I tried the 3rd one just now briefly, but for some reason it couldn't parse my smart output.

The forth one didn't work at all for me, whatever python calls it is using wasn't compatible with my python, and it needs a little more work to get running. (looks freebsd centric)

I'm using Ubuntu server (9.10) on mine.

Answer (score 2):

nagios-core provides a built-in smartd check (no 3rd party plug-ins required).  See [check_ide_smart](http://nagiosplugins.org/node/2).